# Composition of a convex function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is convex function and $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in [a,b]$ and $g:U\rightarrow [a,b]$ is convex function, how to show that $f(g(u)), u\in U$ is convex function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $f$ is increasing. Let $x,y\in U, \lambda\in(0,1)$. From Jensen's inequality follows
$$f(g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y))\leq f(\lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y))\leq
\lambda f(g(x)) + (1-\lambda)f(g(y)),$$
which means the convexity of $f(g(u))$.

Comment: What is exactly Jensen's inequality?  It generalizes the statement that a secant line of a convex function lies above the graph? This is also provided by convexity of a function f? What $f'\geq 0$ has with this?

Comment: If $f' \geq 0$ then $f$ is increasing(there is no connection with convexity). Then I used the Jensen's inequality for convex functions.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality

Comment: Ok, I know that $f'\geq 0$ means that $f$ is increasing, but I don't know why that is important for this problem. Can you explain me that?

Comment: If $f$ is convex on $[a,b],$ then for every $x,y\in[a,b]$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ holds $f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y).$

Comment: Oh, yeah, right now...

Comment: we have that $A=g(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)\leq \lambda g(x) + (1-\lambda)g(y)=B,$ but if we havne't incrising of $f$ we can't write $f(A)\leq f(B),$ which I used in my answer in second inequality.

Comment: aha, ok, I got it :) thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! :)